# Match fixed strings case-insensitively in JQ

Tags: json, jq, string-matching, case-insensitive

Problem:
.contains does not work with case insensitive; where as test and match creates lots of noise cause it is not string matching.

My script

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='v.txt'

while read p; do 
    jq 'if .tweet | contains('\"$p\"') then . |= . + {vendor: '\"$p\"'} else empty end' sfilter.json
done < $filename
```

This was working perfectly; but incase of insensitive content it didn't work | Alternative, test and match also did not pan out cause they did not do the job of string matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` **can** do literal string matching.

```
test("\\Qstring\\E"; "i")
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2IJTvnIzLS)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @OguzIsmail, if your jq's regex engine supports `\\Q...\\E`, you can use that.  However, not all versions of oniguruma (and therefore not all published versions of jq) provide such support; in any case, the following jq def for "de-regexing" a string can help reduce the "noise":

```
def deregex:
  reduce ("\\\\", "\\*", "\\^", "\\?", "\\+", "\\.", "\\!", "\\{", "\\}", "\\[", "\\]", "\\$", "\\|" ) as $c
    (.; gsub( $c; $c));
```

### Example

With the above def, the following:

```
"A*b" |  test( "a*b"| deregex | debug; "i")
```

produces:

```
["DEBUG:","a\\*b"]
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ascii_downcase :

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='v.txt'

while read p; do 
    jq --arg p "$p" '
def contains_i($C; $c):
    $C | ascii_downcase | contains($c|ascii_downcase);

if contains_i(.tweet; $p)
then . |= . + {vendor: $p}
else empty end' sfilter.json
done < $filename
```